# Java lambda functions : a wrapper for a lambda function to with try-catch

Tags: java, lambda, vert.x, functional-interface

I am looking for a [lambda wrapper for the lambda function](http://www.baeldung.com/java-lambda-exceptions) as explained in that post. But with a twist.

we have a lof methods that go:

```
private void method1(RoutingContext ctx, HttpClient client) {
    doAsync1(ctx, client, asyncResult -> {
        try {
            if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {

                ctx.response().setStatusCode(200).end();
            } else {
                LOG.error("doAsync1 failed", asyncResult.cause().getMessage());
                ctx.response().setStatusCode(500);
                ctx.response().end(asyncResult.cause().getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            LOG.error("error doAsync1 failed", ex);
            ctx.response().setStatusCode(500).end();
        }
    });
}

private void method2(RoutingContext ctx, HttpClient client) {
  //... async2 ...
}
```

I d like to get rid of the repetitive try-catch blocks by wrapping the lambda function in the handler. I got lost though.

How can i write a function, like the *safely* below, to simplify my methods?

```
doAsync1(ctx, client, safely(asyncResult -> {
            method1(ctx, httpClient);
        }));
```

(Though safely is probably a bad choice). It would take care of the error handling part.

```
 LOG.error("Failed in Parsing Json", e);
        ctx.response().setStatusCode(500);
        ctx.response().end(e.getMessage());
```

Here is the signature of the functional interface used in the handler of the methods like `doAsync1`

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Handler<E> {
    void handle(E var1);
}
```

Comment: On a Vert.x Web router you can set a [failure handler](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_error_handling). Doesn't that work for you?

Comment: i think we should look into this.. thanks!

Comment: @tsegismont with failureHandlers, can we print stack trace..etc in case of exceptions ?

Comment: or can we rely on this for the uncaught exceptions in our code?

Comment: I ve asked a separate/related question here : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51703680/vertx-using-the-router-failurehandler-for-the-errors-in-async-calls @tsegismont

Answer (score 0, accepted):

a simple solution is as follows :

```
private Handler<AsyncResult<String>> handleSafely(RoutingContext ctx, String method) {
    return asyncResult -> {
        ctx.response().headers().add("content-type", "application/json");

        try {
            if (asyncResult.succeeded()) {
                ctx.response().setStatusCode(200).end(asyncResult.result());
                LOG.info("asyncResult.succeeded()", asyncResult.result());
            } else {
                LOG.error(method + " failed", asyncResult.cause().getMessage());
                ctx.response().setStatusCode(500);
                ctx.response().end(asyncResult.cause().getMessage());
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("error " + method, e);
            ctx.response().setStatusCode(500).end();
        }
    };
}
```

With that we can call :

```
private void method1(RoutingContext ctx, HttpClient client) {
    method1(ctx, client, handleSafely(ctx, "method1"));
}
```