# Vertx - using the Router failureHandler for the errors in async calls

Tags: vert.x

We have recently discovered the [failureHandler](https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_error_handling) in the Vertx router

We thought it could help us get rid of all the repetitive `try-catch` blocks we have. But alas, it seems that the exceptions that are thrown inside the callbacks are not caught by the `failureHandler`.

Example: below, the `failureHandler` is called only for the 3rd case:

```
// Get the user details
        router.get("/user").handler(ctx -> {

            ctx.response().headers().add("content-type", "application/json");

            // some async operation
            userApiImpl.getUser(ctx, httpClient, asyncResult -> {

//          ctx.response().setStatusCode(404).end();    //1 
//          throw new RuntimeException("sth happened"); //2 
                ctx.fail(404);  //3
            });
        });


        // ============================
        // ERROR HANDLER
        // ============================
        router.get("/user").failureHandler(ctx -> {

            LOG.info("Error handler is in the action.");
            ctx.response().setStatusCode(ctx.statusCode()).end("Error occurred in method");
        });
```

1. Is this as expected?
2. Can we somehow declare a global `try-catch` in a router for the exceptions occurring in the async context?

Comment: It is expected that sending a response manually with an error code does not trigger the failure handler. It should be triggered if: 1/ route matches 2/ a handler throws an exception or ctx.fail() is invoked. See https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_error_handling

Comment: i think u can post as an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is expected that sending a response manually with an error code does not trigger the failure handler.

It should be triggered if:

1. the route path matches
2. a handler throws an exception or ctx.fail() is invoked

Here's an example:

```
Route route1 = router.get("/somepath/path1/");

route1.handler(routingContext -> {

  // Let's say this throws a RuntimeException
  throw new RuntimeException("something happened!");

});

Route route2 = router.get("/somepath/path2");

route2.handler(routingContext -> {

  // This one deliberately fails the request passing in the status code
  // E.g. 403 - Forbidden
  routingContext.fail(403);

});

// Define a failure handler
// This will get called for any failures in the above handlers
Route route3 = router.get("/somepath/*");

route3.failureHandler(failureRoutingContext -> {

  int statusCode = failureRoutingContext.statusCode();

  // Status code will be 500 for the RuntimeException or 403 for the other failure
  HttpServerResponse response = failureRoutingContext.response();
  response.setStatusCode(statusCode).end("Sorry! Not today");

});
```

See the [error handling](http://vertx.io/docs/vertx-web/java/#_error_handling) section of the Vert.x Web documentation